# What race did Sauron in LOTR fear the most and why?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron

In the LOTR series and pre-history, which of the major race(s) did Sauron himself fear the most?  And why?

Comment: Well back when Morgoth was around I'm sure he wasn't too fond of elves, but after that most of his conflicts dealt with men. Elves weren't really hanging around ME too much at that point and weren't a threat to his power, and dwarves were concerned primarily with their own business, so it was only men who opposed his power over ME.

I have my doubts to any specifics about who specifically Sauron feared, it wasn't any particular race, only those who could use take and use the ring/oppose his power. A couple of elves, men, and maia all fall into that category.

Comment: At the end, I'm betting that whatever was left of him really feared & hated Hobbits.

Comment: Well, a few Hobbits in particular.  Another hobbit did his bidding for many years, keeping the One ring in his possession (and out of the possession of those who might use it against him) while Sauron gained power. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only time Sauron might have feared a 'race', would have been the Numenoreans, who had an army so strong Sauron's army was too scared to fight them when they came to capture him at the end of the Second Age.  He might have feared his fellow Ainur too, but only if he had a reason to expect them to respond to the degree of a second Host of Valinor, which they did not intend to do.

Comment: Thanks man.  Can I ask in which book did you read this?

Comment: I agree with this, and ties in to the fact that in the books Aragorn (a descendant of the Numenoreans), wins the palantiri mind battle with Sauron and reveals Anduril to him. At which point he shudders in deja vu and realises that he has underestimated the resistance of man. In panic mode (fearing Aragorn will claim the ring for himself), he launches a siege on Minas Tirith instead of doing what any seasoned battle tactician would do, and just launch a few huge rocks at the city from Osgiliath for a few days before making an assault on a weakened defence.